# What is the best way to store root vegetables?

Tags: farming-simulator-2017

I am currently playing a multiplayer game of Farming Simulator with someone else, and we recently tried to do some potato farming, although we came up with a problem regarding storing them. What is the best way to store them which won't cost a lot, seeing as we nearly have run out of cash - loan included - and we don't want to sell or use them right away?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, we both decided to go with (for now) the option which the game recommends - that is, storing them in one of the bays of the two-bay vehicle shelters. Then, we can use the conveyor belts when we want to load up our tippers to load them into the tippers in order to take them to the drop-off point we choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

I store it in train station. It's easier to load and unload.